# How to save change of specific record without save changes of other records in Entity Framework 6

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a WPF application to display a list of [Task] records fetched from db via EF6. Now a user may modified several [Task] records, let's say Task_1, Task_2. But he only want save the Task_1 record back into database. I cannot use `context.Tasks.SaveChanges()` because it will save all changes back to db, including Task_1, Task_2.

**So, is it possible just save changes of a specific record back to db while keep other changes in client and how?**

[image]

**Update-1**

More details:
In my scenario, there is a **[Save]** context menu on each **[Task]** to save current Task. And there is another **[SaveAll]** menu on menubar to save all changes of all task.

And I want to support following cases:

1. User modify and save tasks one by one;
2. User modify all tasks and [SaveAll] tasks;
3. User modify all tasks (eg. Task_1, Task_2, ..., Task_n), then user save Task_1, then user may or may not modify Task_1 again, then user [SaveAll] tasks.

I'm use local SQLite db. And there will be only one single app connect to this db. So I'm using a single app-wide db context. I'm new to Entity Framework, I don't know if its a good practice.

Comment: why don't you detach task_2, or use a new context and set only task_1 to modified?

Comment: There is another menu to enable user SaveAll changes of all tasks,  it will call <code>context.SaveChanges()</code>. So, use a new context may cause the former context become dirty?

Comment: why would it? you could dispose it without calling SaveChanges, it was just for a clean disposal of all attached entries. You should not keep the context open for too long anyways

Comment: added more details in my post

Comment: In this case I would attach all to be saved tasks to the new context (you'll have to save somewhere if they are to be added or modified) and SaveChanges() there. You don't have to use ChangeTracking methods if you don't actually need them.